# Log Message for db get and view files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to provide the custom error log to debug a internal server error in codeigniter.

I have used the try and catch to catch any error in the lines of code but no success. Generic Logs are being generated (from system folder), if I am querying some wrong table. When I checked the database query builder file,
I found that errors are being handled by the internal file but it is not throwing any Exception or Error (script is safely ending after generating the log and displaying error).

```
try{ 
    $data['tags'] = $_SESSION['tags'];
    $data['accId'] = isset($_POST['accId']) ? $_POST['accId'] : '';
    $data['categorySelectionList']=$_SESSION['categorySelectionList'];
    $data['accountSelectionList'] = $_SESSION['accountSelectionList'];
    $_SESSION['transDescList'] = '';
    $this->load->model('Transactions_model');
    $data['transDescList'] = !empty($_SESSION['transDescList']) 
        ? $_SESSION['transDescList'] 
        :  $this->Transactions_model->getTransDescList($this->uid,$_SESSION['tbl_transactions']);
    $this->load->view('frontend/accounts/addTransaction', $data);
}catch(Error $e){
    log_message('error', 'There is a error by the user ');
}
```

Is there any way to produce the custom log from my file like userid, few session data without affecting the core files.

Note: I have achieved this with the help of ajax request. If the request fails I simply make another request to generate the custom log  from xhr.responseText.

Is there any way to achieve this without affecting the core files?

Answer (score 0):

To log your error in codeigniter create `core/MY_Exceptions.php` file to handle custom errors.

Here is a demo of  `core/MY_Exceptions.php` file

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions{


/*
 * Class constructor
 *
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ob_level = ob_get_level();
    /* Note: Do not log messages from this constructor.*/
}


/**
 * Exception Logger
 *
 * Logs PHP generated error messages
 *
 * @param   int $severity   Log level
 * @param   string  $message    Error message
 * @param   string  $filepath   File path
 * @param   int $line       Line number
 * @return  json response
 */
public function log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{
    /*
     *  default log this
     *  and user will get a message of server error
     */
    $severity = isset($this->levels[$severity]) ? $this->levels[$severity] : $severity;
    log_message('error', 'Severity: '.$severity.' --> '.$message.' '.$filepath.' '.$line);

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'Error',
        'error' => '1',
        'message' => 'Server Error ! Please contact administrator !'
    );
    echo json_encode($response);exit;
}


/**
 * 404 Error Handler
 *
 * @uses    CI_Exceptions::show_error()
 *
 * @param   string  $page       Page URI
 * @param   bool    $log_error  Whether to log the error
 * @return  json response
 */
public function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
{
    if (is_cli())
    {
        $heading = 'Not Found';
        $message = 'The controller/method pair you requested was not found.';
    }
    else
    {
        $heading = '404 Page Not Found';
        $message = 'The page you requested was not found.';
    }

    /*
     *  default log this
     *  and user will get a message of server error
     */
    if ($log_error)
    {
        log_message('error', $heading.': '.$page);
    }

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'Error',
        'error' => '1',
        'message' => $message
    );
    echo json_encode($response);exit;
}


/**
 * General Error Page
 *
 * Takes an error message as input (either as a string or an array)
 * and displays it using the specified template.
 *
 * @param   string      $heading    Page heading
 * @param   string|string[] $message    Error message
 * @param   string      $template   Template name
 * @param   int     $status_code    (default: 500)
 *
 * @return  json response
 */
public function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500)
{
    /*
     *  default log this
     *  and user will get a message of server error
     */
    log_message( 'error', print_r($heading,true).': '. print_r($message,true) );

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'Error',
        'error' => '1',
        'message' => 'Server Error ! Please contact administrator !'
    );
    echo json_encode($response);exit;
}


public function show_exception($exception)
{
    /*
     *  default log this
     *  and user will get a message of server error
     */
    log_message( 'error', $exception->getMessage() );

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'Error',
        'error' => '1',
        'message' => 'Server Error ! Please contact administrator !'
    );
    echo json_encode($response);exit;

}


/**
 * Native PHP error handler
 *
 * @param   int $severity   Error level
 * @param   string  $message    Error message
 * @param   string  $filepath   File path
 * @param   int $line       Line number
 * @return  json response
 */
public function show_php_error($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{
    /*
     *  default log this
     *  and user will get a message of server error
     */
    $severity = isset($this->levels[$severity]) ? $this->levels[$severity] : $severity;
    log_message('error', 'Severity: '.$severity.' --> '.$message.' '.$filepath.' '.$line);

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'Error',
        'error' => '1',
        'message' => 'Server Error ! Please contact administrator !'
    );
    echo json_encode($response);exit;
}
```

}

> You can log your error and set response as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what if my need is the customised log or mail to the Admin on the 500 error for some specific methods and for few one custom log(having few data from session), using this approach i have to make the different custom log method.
It has been a improvement which need to be done in codeigniter itself.please refer to the following link [link] (https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5695)